# Add class to link

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, addclass, location-href

I need help adding a class to these links:

```
<a class="campusIcon km-icon" onclick ="window.location.href='indexHome.html'" data-rel="external">Campus</a>
<a class="searchIcon km-icon"  onclick ="window.location.href='indexListView.html'"  data-rel="external">Search</a>
<a class="mapIcon km-icon"  onclick ="window.location.href='indexKBlock.html'"  data-rel="external">Map</a>
<a class="favIcon km-icon" onclick ="window.location.href='indexChart.html'" data-rel="external">Fav</a>
```

The class I want to add is `km-state-active`. If I add the class inside an `onClick` event then I get my class is added but `location.href` does not work.

So, what's the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: Show the code that causes `location.href` to fail.

Comment: Incredible. Posting your question I bet there was at least 30 already posted questions with the same problem.

Comment: @Danis beside each answer you see a voting section(with a up and down arrow) and a tick sign below it, please make habit to click on it to accept answer that help you, to make everyone happy to help..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Can I Add a "Selected" Class Based on URL with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079788/how-can-i-add-a-selected-class-based-on-url-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?:

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("km-state-active");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**HTML:**

```
<a class="campusIcon km-icon"  href="indexHome.html" data-rel="external">Campus</a> 
<a class="searchIcon km-icon" href="indexListView.html" data-rel="external">Search</a> 
<a class="mapIcon km-icon" href="indexKBlock.html" data-rel="external">Map</a> 
<a class="favIcon km-icon" href="indexChart.html" data-rel="external">Fav</a>​
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("a").on('click', function() {
   $(this).addClass("km-state-active").attr('href', 'YOUR_URL');
});
```

Comment: no, there is another problem...I can not bind click event with two action. In my case it adds class or make location.href

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using inline code to handle the click on an anchor tag? Why not:

**JS**

```
$("a").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("km-state-active");
});
```

**HTML**

```
<a class="campusIcon km-icon"  href="indexHome.html" data-rel="external">Campus</a> 
<a class="searchIcon km-icon" href="indexListView.html" data-rel="external">Search</a> 
<a class="mapIcon km-icon" href="indexKBlock.html" data-rel="external">Map</a> 
<a class="favIcon km-icon" href="indexChart.html" data-rel="external">Fav</a>​
```

**Additional Information**

This is a decent article (old but good): [Why Inline CSS And JavaScript Code Is Such A Bad Thing](http://css.dzone.com/news/why-inline-css-and-javascript-)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use inline script. its a bad practice. Update you markup to look similar to this.

```
<a class="campusIcon km-icon" href ="indexHome.html" data-rel="external">Campus</a>
```

And use jQuery to add the class on click

```
$("a").on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass("km-state-active");
});
```